# How can I send an OpenCV-Image via json to an Flask Docker-Container?

Tags: python, json, opencv, docker, flask

I followed Miguel Grinbergs Tutorial to have a flask video streaming server with OpenCV (see here https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/flask-video-streaming-revisited). I got it up and running in a Docker Container and it works fine. Now I wanted to have to video source in another Docker-Container, because I don't want to have OpenCV in the flask web container. 
Now I've got a problem with the Json-Serialization. 
What I thought is the best way, is to encode the OpenCV-image to bytes and base64encode it, then dump it in json and send it to the flask-container, where I load the json and base64-decode the image. 
But that doesn't work. In some frames I get an padding-error, in some no errors, but the frame isn't shown in the browser.

Does someone has an idea?

```
def frames():
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(Camera.video_source)
    _, img = camera.read()
    img_bytes = cv2.imencode('.jpg', img)[1].tobytes()
    img_as_text = base64.b64encode(img_bytes)
    data = {"image": str(img_as_text)}
    data_json = json.dumps(data)
    new_json = json.loads(data_json)
    im = new_json['image']
    img_original = base64.b64decode(im)
    yield img_original
```